# Error message: "AMDEP" was never defined

Tags: autoconf, automake

I have a `configure.ac` in which I enable different compilers by different configure options. The `configure` script is generated successfully but at the end (call to `AC_OUTPUT`) I get an error message:

```
configure: error: conditional "AMDEP" was never defined.
Usually this means the macro was only invoked conditionally.
```

Sadly looking into `config.log` does not help and I have no idea what causes this error or where to start searching.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently you cannot embed `AM_PROG_CC`, `AM_PROG_CPP` or `AM_PROG_CXX` in an `if` block (for whatever reason).
Solution was to set a variable in the `if` block and pass it to AM_PROG_*.

Comment: There is a bit of additional info and explanation at http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.sysutils.autoconf.bugs/549. Short: Tests shouldn't be done conditionally.

Comment: @JonnyJD That link seems to be dead :( Are you aware of another source of that info?

Comment: Unfortunately even archive.org doesn't seem to have this page archived and I don't know of another place. Sorry. The shutdown of gmane is a problem.